# How to remove background image from digram?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, background-image, diagram, removechild

```
  onUploadRemove = () => {
        console.log("delete");
        console.log("delete state:", this.state.backgroundImge);
        this.setState({
            backgroundImge: null // Remove the background image
        }, () => {
            console.log("Updated state:", this.state.backgroundImge);
            this.forceUpdate();
        });
    };
```

on call this function state of background image is change to null but image is showing why

```
  onUploadRemove = () => {
        console.log("delete");
        console.log("delete state:", this.state.backgroundImge);
        this.setState({
            backgroundImge: null // Remove the background image
        }, () => {
            console.log("Updated state:", this.state.backgroundImge);
            this.forceUpdate();
        });
    };
```

create that function and want to remove background image from screen

Comment: How removing background image is related to a state update?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.